# Compute a laplace transform

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

> Compute $\mathcal{L} [e^{-2x} \sin x]$

So I want to do $\int_0^\infty e^{-2x} \sin x e^{-px} \, dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-(p+2)x}\sin x \, dx$

But due to the way $e$ and $\sin x$ integrates I dont know where to go from here?

Comment: It is usually a waste of time to start out of scratch from the definition of L.T.. Why don't you use Laplace Transform **Tables** (may be you use too restricted ones) ? There is an entry for the Laplace Transform $e^{at}\sin(\omega t)$...

Comment: A standard trick is to integrate by parts (in this case twice), and get something like $$ \int_0^\infty e^{-(p+2)x} \sin x\,dx = \text{SOMETHING} + \left(\text{something} \cdot \int_0^\infty e^{-(p+2)x} \sin x\,dx\right). $$ Then you subtract the last parenthesized expression from both sides, getting $$ (1 - \text{something}) \int_0^\infty e^{-(p+2)x} \sin x\,dx = \text{SOMETHING} + \text{constant} $$ and then divide both sides by $(1-\text{something})$. Two of the answers below (so far) give some details. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Try integration by parts, twice.  When you have done that you find you have gone in a circle...you should have something along the lines of:

$$f(p) - g(p)\int_0^\infty e^{-(p+2)x} \sin x \,dx$$

And you have the same integral that you already know that you didn't know how to solve... but you are not dead yet.

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-(p+2)x} \sin x \, dx = f(p) - g(p)\int_0^\infty e^{-(p+2)x} \sin x \, dx\\
(1+g(p)) \int_0^\infty e^{-(p+2)x} \sin x \, dx = f(p)\\
\int_0^\infty e^{-2x} \sin x e^{-px} \, dx = \frac {f(p)}{1+g(p)}$$

Alternatively say: $\sin x = \frac 1{2i} (e^{ix} - e^{-ix})$

$$\frac 12 \int_0^\infty e^{-(p+2-i)x} - e^{-(p+2+i)x} \, dx$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(p+2)x}\sin x dx=\text{Im}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(p+2-i)x}\:dx=\text{Im}\:\frac1{p+2-i}=\frac1{(p+2)^2+1}, \quad p>-2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$J=\int_0^\infty e^{-2x} \sin xe^{-px} \, dx =\int_0^\infty e^{-(p+2)x} \sin x\,dx=-\int_0^\infty e^{-(p+2)x} \, d(\cos x) =\\ =-\left( \left. e^{-(p+2)x \cos x} \right|_0^\infty +(p+2) \int_0^\infty e^{-(p+2)x} \cos x \, dx \right) =\\ =1-(p+2) \int_0^\infty e^{-(p+2)x} \cos x \, dx =1-(p+2) \left( \left. e^{ -(p+2)x \sin x } \right|_0^\infty +(p+2) \underbrace { \int_0^\infty e^{ -(p+2)x} \sin x \, dx}_J \right) $$
so the answer is

> $$ J=1-(p+2)^2 J\Rightarrow \quad J=\frac 1 {1+(p+2)^2 } $$

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you want to understand how to find the transform using the integral definition and others have already indicated ways to do that.

But for the sake of variety here is how to prove it using only linearity and the property $\mathcal{L}\{y^\prime\}=s\mathcal{L}\{y\}-y(0)$.

Let $y=e^{-2x}\sin(x)$. Then

\begin{equation}
y^\prime=-2e^{-2x}\sin(x)+e^{-2x}\cos(x)
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
y^{\prime\prime}=3e^{-2x}\sin(x)-4e^{-2x}\cos(x)
\end{equation}

So

\begin{equation}
y^{\prime\prime}+4y^\prime=-5e^{-2x}\sin(x) \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Note that $y(0)=0$ and $y^\prime(0)=1$. Take the Laplace transform of both sides.

\begin{eqnarray}
s\mathcal{L}\{y^\prime\}-y^\prime(0)+4[s\mathcal{L}\{y\}-y(0)] &=-5\mathcal{L}\{y\}\\
s[s\mathcal{L}\{y\}-y(0)]-1+4s\mathcal{L}\{y\}&=-5\mathcal{L}\{y\}\\
\left(s^2+4s+5\right)Y(s)&=1\\
Y(s)&=\dfrac{1}{(s+2)^2+1}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**$$F(s-p)=\int_0^\infty{e^{-(s-p)t}f(t)}=$$
$$\int_0^\infty{e^{-st}e^{pt}f(t)}=\mathcal L(e^{pt}f(t))$$
Using this to compute $\mathcal{L} [e^{-2x} \sin x]$ gives:
$$\mathcal{L} (e^{-2x} \sin x)=\dfrac{1}{(s+2)^2+1}$$
Computing $\mathcal{L} [e^{-(p+2)x} \sin x]$ gives:
$$\mathcal{L} (e^{-(p+2)x} \sin x)=\dfrac{1}{(s+p+2)^2+1}$$